# Trying to pass 5 values of card to a function, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am doing a card game and this game when you click deal_hand, it will deal a 5 hand card from my class Card() (just the values and display them). Then I'm suppose to average them out and display it (Divide by 5 and display). I'm not sure how to do this. Here is the Class card:

```
    import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.face_value = ''


def deal(self):
    self.set_value(random.randint(1,13))   



def set_value(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.set_face_value()                                


def set_face_value(self):
     faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three",  4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}
     self.face_value = faces[self.value]

def __str__(self):
    return self.face_value
```

main()

I haven't done the other function because I have no idea how to do it but it goes something like this:

```
    def deal_hand():

        card1 = Card()
        card1.deal()


    for i in range(5):
        card1.deal()
        print("Your 5 hand card is")
        print(card1)
```

I can't get the program to display a hand of 5 cards. I'm sorry if this is hard to understand, but the program is suppose to display this:

```
    The 5-card hand is: 
    Jack
    Three
    Queen
    Two
    Seven
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You have defined a function deal_hand but you haven't invoked it? Card1 object is not initialized inside for loop.

Comment: I think you need to change your abstractions. A card is a member of a hand. Hands are dealt.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: There are *many* examples of playing card games on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the web. How is it that these didn't help you design your classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach that is much nicer, is to use properties

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def shuffle(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1, 13)

    @property
    def face_value(self):
        faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four",
                 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight",
                 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen",
                 13: "King"}
        return faces[self.value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.face_value


def deal_hand():
    card = Card()
    print("Your 5 hand card is")
    for i in range(5):
        card.shuffle()
        print(card)


deal_hand()
```

output:

```
Your 5 hand card is
Seven
Eight
Ace
Seven
Ace
```

Comment: This is better! This is what I'm trying to fully do but for the program, is just not coming out right.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183928/generating-a-card-class-for-my-other-program

Comment: I finally figure it out!! thank you so much for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct, give this a try.

Also move `print("Your 5 hand card is")` out of the for loop.

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.face_value = ''    

    def deal(self):
        self.set_value(random.randint(1,13))    

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.set_face_value()    

    def set_face_value(self):
         faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four", 
             5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 
             9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 
             13: "King"}
         self.face_value = faces[self.value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.face_value


def deal_hand():    
    card1 = Card()
    card1.deal()    

    print("Your 5 hand card is")
    for i in range(5):
        card1.deal()
        print(card1)

deal_hand()
```

Output:

```
Your 5 hand card is
Queen
King
Jack
Queen
Four
```

Comment: Whenever I'm trying to import it to another program I get this:         
line 9, in deal
    self.value(random.randint(1,13))
AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: import classcard

def main():    
    card1 = Card()
    card1.deal()    

    print("Your 5 hand card is")
    for i in card(5):
        
        print(card1)

Comment: it looks like in the `deal` method you wrote `self.value(random.randint(1,13)) `  not `self.set_value(random.randint(1,13)) ` let me know if this is not the case, also you wrote `for i in card(5):` do you mean `for i in range(5): `

Comment: I switched out the self.set to self.value

Comment: also I did try to say for i in range(5): and I end up getting this error line 9, in deal
    self.value(random.randint(1,13))
AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: I have three questions, as I cant guess what you have changed so cant answer your question.
1-When you use the code I posted what does not work? 
2-What changes did you make?
3-After your changes what does not work?

Comment: okay, I'm sorry this is hard to explain with this application. I switch out the deal method with the one i had self.set_value(random.randint(1,13)) to self.set_value(random.randint(1,13)), Than I went to the other program that will execute the class card (after being imported) and will display 5 cards.

Comment: Never mind! I got it all figure out! thank you!