# Implementing a `Card` class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, playing-cards

This program is about defining a class `Card` that generates a card whenever it is called (rank only, no suit). I did it a different way than the instructions so now I'm extremely confused on how this program is suppose to work.

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0

    def deal(self):
        self.__value(random.randint(1,13))      

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = set_face_value

    def get_value():



    def set_face_value(self):
         faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three",  4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}
         self.face_value = faces[self.value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.face_value
```

I had to erase so of it because I'm still trying to figure what I did wrong. This is her response for my program:

```
import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0       # THIS SHOULD BE PRIVATE - PUT __ AS THE FIRST
                             # TWO CHARACTERS IN THE NAME
        self.face_value = '' # YOU DO NOT SAVE THIS
                             # YOU SHOULD HAVE ONLY ONE DATA ATTRIBUTE


    def deal(self):
        self.set_value(random.randint(1,13))
        # THIS METHOD DOES NOT NEED TO CALL "set_value
        # IT SHOULD JUST SET THE self.__value ATTRIBUTE



    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.set_face_value()  # READ THE ASSIGNMENT - YOU DO NOT HAVE A
                               # SET FOR THE FACE VALUE

    # YOU SHOULD NOT HAVE ANY SUCH METHOD IN YOUR CLASS
    def set_face_value(self):
         faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three",  4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen", 13: "King"}
         self.face_value = faces[self.value]

    # YOU SHOULD HAVE A "find_face_value" METHOD THAT RETURNS THE FACE VALUE BASED ON THE VALUE OF THE
    # PRIVATE DATA ATTRIBUTE "__value"

    # THIS IS NOT CORRECT    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.face_value
```

And these are her criticisms:

- You will define a `deal` method in your class Card: this method will deal one card (using the random number generator).
- You will define a `find_face_value` method that will return the face value for the card object. You will remove the `display_face_value` function from your program.
- Your `deal_hand` function will pass the list of objects to the `display_hand` function and the `hand stats` function, (send 5 cards from the class Card to the function)

So, my main problems is executing `deal_hand` and showing a hand of 5 and it will show like this:

```
    The 5-card hand is: 
         Jack
         Three
         Queen
         Two
         Seven
    The average value of your hand is:
         7.0
    #Also it should display like this
    print("Your card is", card)
```

English is not my first language so is hard for me to understand what it really wants.
This is the Data attributes they are asking:

```
Class name:              Card
 Data attributes:        __value
 Methods:                __init__()
                         deal()
                         set_value()
                         get_value()
                         find_face_value()
                         __str__()
```

Comment: the main error I get is: line 9, in deal
    self.value(random.randint(1,13))
AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Please move your comment into your question. That's very important information.

Comment: Yes please add that error in your question, like in the first paragraph. You need to state what the motivating error was, people frown on things that appear like someone posting an entire class definition and saying "this doesn't work" - not that that's what you did here. Also I did some edits that I hope improve clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are being asked to do this in a very specific way. 
I don't believe it is a good way of doing it either.
It looks like you teacher calls fields with `__` at the start private, as if it was a java private field, be aware this is not the case. In python, if you want to use java style getters and setters you should use the `@property` annotator.
There are many other improvements that could be made, I have not done this due to the requirements, I hope this helps.

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0

    def deal(self):
        self.__value = random.randint(1, 13)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def find_face_value(self):
        faces = {1: "Ace", 2: "two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four",
                 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight",
                 9: "Nine", 10: "Ten", 11: "Jack", 12: "Queen",
                 13: "King"}
        return faces[self.__value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.find_face_value()


def main():
    card = Card()
    total = 0
    print("Your 5 hand card is:")
    for i in range(5):
        card.deal()
        print("Your card is", card)
        total += card.get_value()
    print("The average value of your hand is:")
    print(total/5)


main()
```

Comment: I appreciate you, you really did help me understand this. It was just complicated putting everything to get it.

Comment: Yes, the teacher is pushing a way-out-of-date Java hybrid and should be using Python `property`, not getters and setters. I feel sorry for the OP having to put up with that level of instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I did it differently, if I understood correctly, your suppose to deal 5 cards out.

```
from random import *

suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

shuffle(deck)
hand = deck[:5]
print (hand)
```

There are five cards which do not repeat in your hand for the output.

Comment: yes something like that, but I don'y really need the suits. I need to use this on my class Card and be able to execute it in other programs. That's why she is making us use the Card Class to be able to execute it everytime is needed.